# Custom shape's bone

Tags: bones

I'm doing a rig and I want to modify the shape of my bones: in particular the control bones of torso.

Here a simplified situation: I want to change the shape of my octahedral bone in the circle behind.

[image]

The problem is this: in pose mode my bone, after choosing the custom shape, disappears.

[image]

Furthermore if I switch to object mode the bone will come back with the circle shape.

[image]

Here the point is: I need tools to move my mesh easily and a circle around the waist is perfect but in pose mode doesn't appear  . . . i can't understand why since the method used should be right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To see the custom bone shape displayed you need to check the ***Wireframe*** checkbox in a *Display* panel of the *Bone* header. 
[image]

Also, it is a good habit to keep your custom bone shapes in the last layer. Move your mesh to layer 20th then. Being in *Object Mode* select both layers with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and transform your custom mesh (using <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>) to fit the bone position. Then enter the *Edit Mode* and change the mesh's shape. The bone shape will behave the same.
[image]