# Custom shapes keep dissapearing after being assigned to bone

Tags: rigging, bones

I created a rig for a [model](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/65892) I found on blendswap to get some rigging practice. But when I try to change the pole targets to a custom shape the bone disappears but the name stays there. And then when i check hide the name disappears. How can i assign this custom shape without it disappearing? the custom shape is called PoleTarget. Here is my [blendfile](https://gist.github.com/AlexDvorak/0f26f88fb325e87125986cf9adc8a4bf/archive/0a0b3fbcc46273320934984f4a4b0b2bdfeab72a.zip) The custom bone shape does not show up even in object mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom shape's bone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43051/custom-shapes-bone)

Comment: the circle doesnt appear even in object mode

Comment: so no duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by converting the curve to mesh with Alt-C. The custom shape on the bone then became available.